# How to load the Symfony component configuration files if not using the whole framework?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to bootstrap a simple microservice type of application with the Symfony router and DI component, but without using the `symfony/skeleton` package as a starting point.

Routing works, but DI does not. Looking at the [documentation of the service container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html), it is unclear of how my app would actually use the `config/services.yaml` file. I don't understand when is it loaded, how it is loaded, and how I would tell Symfony to use a `services.php` instead?

Similarly, if I install new composer packages, they dump some `.yaml` config files in `config/packages/`. Would I then have to load these files manually, using the `config` component?

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there any good reason not to use more components? Manually implementing all the stuff you need might be more work, and I don't think that there are so huge performance gains

Comment: By "more components", you mean to just create my microservice as a Symfony app? I think I underestimated the learning curve of using the components in a standalone app.

Comment: With respect to the last paragraph in your question, any package which deposits a file under config/packages is actually a Symfony bundle and is specifically designed to be used inside of the Symfony framework.  So the answer is: you basically will not be able to use those specific packages.  Configuration is a big part of the framework.

Comment: If you have not already I would suggest reading about the [Symfony MicroKernel](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-improved-microkernel) and maybe starting there.  Still uses the framework bundle but gives you more or less complete control over configuration.

Comment: @Michael yes, exactly. Unless you are really sure that you **want** to implement all the stuff the framework provides on your own, I would vote for using a proper Symfony app.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the DI link in your question points to the framework documentation.  If you want to understand how to use DI standalone then look at the [DI component documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html).

Comment: @Cerad Interestingly enough, the documentation states that there's a [standalone usage for the PSR-18 client](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#psr-18-and-psr-17), even though it seems to require some Symfony bundles.

Comment: You are confusing bundles and packages.  Symfony bundles are packages and are specifically designed to be used within the Symfony framework.  Bundles are typically wrappers which integrate standalone libraries into the Symfony framework.  However, Symfony also has a number of packages which can be used outside of the framework.  Symfony calls these packages components.  They could have just called them libraries but oh well.  The http-client in your link is a component not a bundle.

Comment: I took a closer look at the http-client and I can understand some of the confusion perhaps.  The docs show "Framework Use" vs "Standalone Use" on the same page.  Have not noticed this approach for other components before.  So you have to be careful as which code you are looking at.  You can use the http-client without any Symfony bundles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this typically happens (in a Symfony application) in the application Kernel, which is instantiated and booted by the "front-controller" script (e.g. `public/index.php`).

In the [default Symfony 5 provided kernel you'll find this](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/5.1/src/Kernel.php):

```
protected function configureContainer(ContainerConfigurator $container): void
{
    $container->import('../config/{packages}/*.yaml');
    $container->import('../config/{packages}/'.$this->environment.'/*.yaml');

    if (is_file(\dirname(__DIR__).'/config/services.yaml')) {
        $container->import('../config/services.yaml');
        $container->import('../config/{services}_'.$this->environment.'.yaml');
    } elseif (is_file($path = \dirname(__DIR__).'/config/services.php')) {
        (require $path)($container->withPath($path), $this);
    }
}
```

This loads all `*.yaml` files in the `config/packages` directories, and load the file `config/services.php` **but only if the file `config/services.yaml` does not exist**.

If you are building your own application without using the framework, you'll have to load these files wherever it makes sense for you application.

With the reduced footprint of Symfony 5, building your own is likely not particularly cost-effective, you can use the minimal `symfony/skeleton` and you would already have a very "micro" starting point, without having to spend time deciding these things.

If you are set on "building your own", either because of specific requirements or as a learning exercise, I recommend you reading this part of the documentation: [Create your own PHP Framework](https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html). It's a very useful way of learning how the many pieces fit together.

Comment: I want to create a standalone PHP app, not a Symfony App, and use the Routing and Dependency Injection component. I understand now that I would have to manually load config files in this case. In the case of the DI component, does this mean I cannot just type hint a class in my ie. construcor method, but have to manually register them in the container first? At least that seems to be suggested here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html

Comment: you can use autowire just fine. you just need to enable autowiring as explained [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html). If you do not want to define each service manually, you'll likely want to `load()` them as shown [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/import.html)